# Undefined offset in a multiple query

Tags: php, mysql

Output of the Query:

[Query Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH0Sj.png)

I can now output the date and time a employee has logged in.
What I want to do now is to use the output of the time column in a `TIMEDIFF FUNCTION` so I can use it in computing the salary of that person. The thing is I don't know how to debug this error, any help is much appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
 border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","september-system");


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "SELECT User_ID, MIN(TIME(Time)) as time, DATE(Time) as day FROM records GROUP BY User_ID, day ORDER BY User_ID, day;";
$sql .= "SELECT TIMEDIFF('08:00:00', '07:00:00');";

// Execute multi query
if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql))
{
do
{
// Store first result set
if ($result=mysqli_store_result($con)) {
  echo "<table><tr><th>USER ID</th><th>TIME</th><th>DATE</th></tr>";
 // output data of each row
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row[0]. "</td><td>" . $row[1]. 
    "</td><td>" . $row[2]. "</td></tr>";

    }
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
}
while(mysqli_more_results($con) && mysqli_next_result($con));
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Result of `var_dump($row)`

```
C:\wamp64\www\test1.php:36:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '14:31:24' (length=8)
  2 => string '2016-09-09' (length=10)

C:\wamp64\www\test1.php:36:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '15:02:05' (length=8)
  2 => string '2016-09-10' (length=10)

C:\wamp64\www\test1.php:36:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '00:48:18' (length=8)
  2 => string '2016-09-12' (length=10)

C:\wamp64\www\test1.php:36:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '18:39:46' (length=8)
  2 => string '2016-09-14' (length=10)

C:\wamp64\www\test1.php:36:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '18:54:04' (length=8)
  2 => string '2016-09-15' (length=10)

C:\wamp64\www\test1.php:36:
  array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '08:32:15' (length=8)
  2 => string '2016-09-16' (length=10)

C:\wamp64\www\test1.php:36:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '10:06:37' (length=8)
  2 => string '2016-09-17' (length=10)

C:\wamp64\www\test1.php:36:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '17:09:14' (length=8)
  2 => string '2016-09-18' (length=10)

C:\wamp64\www\test1.php:36:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '12:32:52' (length=8)
  2 => string '2016-09-19' (length=10)

C:\wamp64\www\test1.php:36:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '09:11:34' (length=8)
  2 => string '2016-09-20' (length=10)

C:\wamp64\www\test1.php:36:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '08:35:24' (length=8)
  2 => string '2016-09-21' (length=10)

C:\wamp64\www\test1.php:36:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '21:42:45' (length=8)
  2 => string '2016-09-22' (length=10)

C:\wamp64\www\test1.php:36:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '10:08:21' (length=8)
  2 => string '2016-09-23' (length=10)

C:\wamp64\www\test1.php:36:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => string '00:12:38' (length=8)
  2 => string '2016-09-16' (length=10)

C:\wamp64\www\test1.php:36:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '3' (length=1)
  1 => string '23:52:06' (length=8)
  2 => string '2016-09-15' (length=10)

C:\wamp64\www\test1.php:36:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '4' (length=1)
  1 => string '09:11:54' (length=8)
  2 => string '2016-09-16' (length=10)

C:\wamp64\www\test1.php:36:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '4' (length=1)
  1 => string '12:22:07' (length=8)
  2 => string '2016-09-21' (length=10)

C:\wamp64\www\test1.php:36:
array (size=1)
  0 => string '01:00:00' (length=8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you comment this part, your problem will be gone.

```
$sql .= "SELECT TIMEDIFF('08:00:00', '07:00:00');";
```

The output of this query is a simple array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 01:00:00 )
```

Comment: I need to have the difference of the log in time and 7 AM for me to compute the deductions on the salary of the employee who are always late. Any suggestion on how to do that? Thanks for the response